# Why are female singers criticised when singing live more than male singers?

Tags: history, live-music, music-business

I mean, there are a lot of talks, youtube videos, criticism, ect about female singers when they perform live (she can't sing live, she can't hit that high note like records, she doesn't sound like record, etc.). It seems, people are more interesting in female singers vocal abilities more than male singers ?! We also have the term DIVA for female singers, but is there any similar term for male singers?

Is there any reason for that? I am just curious.

Comment: Because [society](https://www.glamour.com/story/criticism-from-boss-differs-between-men-women). It isn't just singers.

Comment: Why are female [anything] criticized when doing [anything] more than male [anything]?

Comment: This would rather be opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

The term "diva" is really a descendant of the *prima donna* ("first lady" = lead female role) in opera. *Prima uomo* means "first man," but this term is very rarely used compared to *prima donna*.

I can't offer a definite answer for your main question, but I wonder if it might be related to genre. The genres in which female singers dominate have very different singing styles than the more male-dominated genres, so it might be that the female-dominated genres are more open to that type of criticism.

Answer (score 3):

In specific genres, this may be true.  However, in genres where the singer is mostly acting as a host - such as in vaudeville or in hiphop - the female singer won't be judged as much.  In others where the singer is the performer, there does seem to be a double standard.  Rex Harrison was mocked for continuously talking his numbers but continued to be billed onto the top of the ticket.

That said, a lot of female singers tend to try and exploit their youthful voices in a competitive manner, exploiting their high registers to the point where it becomes their trademarks.  Mariah Carey is an example of that and as far as I can tell she hasn't figured out a way to sing those old numbers with a maturing voice.  Singers who begin in alto ranges have an easier time.  [Ginette Reno's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBxTsJ1XiqM) career has been going on for many decades without anyone questioning her range.  And some singers will build a repertoire associated with varied singing ranges.  Céline Dion sang as a soprano at 12 years old but progressed towards mezzo-soprano in her peak years as an adult.  She was able to do this by constantly recording and having people entertained by the current songs.

Pregnancy and motherhood interfere with consistent performance and recordings and so gaps between performances make people recall the older songs more readily.  That, of course, creates, problems.  The remedy seems to be to constantly take on new songs and not dwell on those old songs so much.

Apart from that, whiners will be whiners.  You could shun their responses or you could also prod them along to accept the new songs that they are doing.